# FileNotFoundException while running as Jar - Java

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

I have written my java codes using eclipse and iam reading a file and processing the codes. The key.txt is present in the same folder as src .

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("KEY.txt"));
```

Now after i compile the jar and place both the jar and file in the same folder and execute  iam getting FilenotFoundException. The program works if i run inside Eclipse reading the file perfectly.

The jar file and the key.txt always have to be in the same folder.
Please let me know how can I solve this issue of FilenotFoundException.

Comment: you are using eclipse so, you have added this jar as library or as simply put into folder?, and key.txt is inside jar file? can you share your folder structure?

Comment: When running your App from the jar are you in the same directory as the one which contains both the jar file as well as the txt file ?

Comment: 1) If the resource is either editable, or added after download, put the `KEY.txt` into a sub-directoy (perhaps based on the package of the main class) of `user.home`.  It is a reproducible path that should be readable & writable.  2) If it is static and provided in the Jar at the same time as the app., access it by URL obtained from `this.getClass().getResource("path/name.type")`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have opens a file in the current working directory, which is the directory where you started the Java process from.

This is completely unrelated to where the jar file is located.

How do you execute the jar file?

If the key file is right next to the jar file, this should work:

```
java -jar theJar.jar
```

But this will not (because the path to the key is now "test/KEY.txt" ):

```
java -jar test/theJar.jar
```

When you run a program in Eclipse, the current working directory is (usually) the project root folder.

An alternative to consider (if the file does not need to be edited by the user) is to put the key file *into* the jar file. Then it will not get lost, and you can load it via the classloader.

Another good option is to have the user provide the path to the file, via command line parameter or system property.

Or make a batch file / shell script that makes sure that you are always running from the proper directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how should i modify my program so I can have the jar and key.txt in the same folder irrespective of any folder the user provide . If they are both together it should work.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put these files with class file of the running class, because the current directory is the directory in which the class file is stored, not the source java file.

Comment: Thanks . Let me try and get back to you.